# How to add an integer to a date field

Tags: odoo

Im a beginner in odoo . So Im doing a Module called Hotel management and I have an integer field called " Expected_days" where the user can add the number of days he will stay and I have another field that is a date time filed where he can choose the check in date . So I need to add the expected days with the check in date to get the new date . Im doing in odoov14.

EX: if user add 3 days and check in  date is 22/04/2018

then I need to get  25/04/2018 in a new field " expected_date".

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class HotelAccommodation(models.Model):
    _name = 'accommodation.room'
    _description = 'Reception'
    _rec_name = 'name_sequence'


expected_days = fields.Integer(string='Expected days')
expected_date = fields.Datetime(string='Expected date')


@api.onchange('expected_days')
def onchange_next_date(self):
    if self.checkin_date:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.checkin_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        expected_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.expected_days)
```

My error:

```
 in onchange_next_date
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.checkin_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lenovo/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/lenovo/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class HotelAccommodation(models.Model):
    _name = 'accommodation.room'
    _description = 'Reception'
    _rec_name = 'name_sequence'


expected_days = fields.Integer(string='Expected days')
expected_date = fields.Datetime(string='Expected date')


@api.onchange('expected_days')
def onchange_next_date(self):
    if self.checkin_date:
        self.expected_date = self.checkin_date + timedelta(days=self.expected_days)
```

Comment: Thank you , may I know what was the real issue with my code .

Comment: Yeah sure. First issue was with datetime `strptime` method you were passing `datetime field` in it but this method takes `string field`. Second was there is no need to convert datetime into any other `format` to add `days/years` etc. Third was you forgot to add `self` before `expected_date` because you're assign data to current object field.